# Can I use syntax highlighting on an unwritten buffer?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, buffers

I pasted some code into a new, unwritten buffer in Vim.  I'd like to do some quick edits on the code without saving it to a file, but it hurts my eyes to look at code without syntax highlighting.  Can I use syntax highlighting without writing it to a file?  I don't want to write it to a file so I don't have to delete the file when I'm done.

Comment: What are you editing that youre not saving when done?

Comment: A SQL query that I'm going to run once.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to setting the syntax, setting the filetype brings indent options (if you have those on), mappings, and other filetype specific vimscript to bear on your code. So I recommend

```
:set filetype=java
```

Which we typically abbreviate in interactive use as

```
:set ft=java
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the syntax highlighting by doing:

```
:set syntax=java
```

This will work in the unwritten buffer. Change `java` for the appropriate value.

Comment: Or even `set filetype` if you have mappings/other goodies to use.

Comment: Thanks, alanboy.  That works.
@D.BenKnoble That's even better.  I'll mark that as the correct answer if you make an answer.